# Do static constructors run as CERs?

Tags: c#, clr, threadabortexception, thread-abort, cer

I'm testing the below code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var t = new Thread(() => 
    {
        var m = new MyCls();
        m.DoWork();       
    });
    t.Start();

    // simulate time-consuming job
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    t.Abort();
    Console.Write("\nDone");
}


public class MyCls
{
    static MyCls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } 
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("executing DoWork..");
    }
}
```

And the output I get is:

```
0123456789
Done
```

It seems that `t.Abort()` call is blocking the main thread until the execution of the static constructor finishes, and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8):

> The thread that calls `Abort` might block if the thread that is being aborted is in a protected region of code, such as a catch block, finally block, or **constrained execution region**.

My questions is:

1. Do static constructors really run as constrained execution regions (CERs) ?
2. If yes, what other code blocks that run as CERs ?

Comment: Please be aware that `Thread.Abort()` can corrupt the run-time. The only safe time to call abort is when you're trying to crash out of your application entirely - i.e. aborting all threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes I'm aware that `Thread.Abort()` is a bad practice, I'm just trying to learn how the CLR behaves in some situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that static constructors are *guaranteed to have completed*, almost.

Static constructors can be called explicitly with [`RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.runclassconstructor?view=netframework-4.8) which '*Ensures that the type initializer (also known as a static constructor) for the specified type has been run'*.

In your example, the code could be written as follows.

```
var t = new Thread(() =>
{
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(MyCls).TypeHandle);
  var m = new MyCls();
});
```

`RunClassConstructor` calls [`_RunClassConstructor`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/runtimehelpers.cs,3f64db1811e8b4bb,references) which is annotated with the following comment.

> In the absence of class constructor deadlock conditions, the call is further guaranteed to have completed.

```
// RunClassConstructor causes the class constructor for the given type to be triggered
// in the current domain.  After this call returns, the class constructor is guaranteed to
// have at least been started by some thread.  In the absence of class constructor
// deadlock conditions, the call is further guaranteed to have completed.
//
// This call will generate an exception if the specified class constructor threw an 
// exception when it ran. 
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void _RunClassConstructor(RuntimeType type);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Update: The question is about `t.Abort()` blocking, not interrupting, so this answer is hardly relevant :)*

---

The documentation for [Thread.Abort Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8) explicitly states that Abort may abort a static constructor.

> When a thread calls Abort on itself, the effect is similar to throwing an exception; the ThreadAbortException happens immediately, and the result is predictable. However, if one thread calls Abort on another thread, the abort interrupts whatever code is running. There is also a chance that a static constructor could be aborted. In rare cases, this might prevent instances of that class from being created in that application domain.

and

> For example, calling Thread.Abort may prevent static constructors from executing or prevent the release of unmanaged resources.

---

While your example elegantly shows that a static constructor may not be interrupted, there is no guarantee for this behaviour.

---

## UPDATE

Here is an example where the static ctor is interrupted with Abort().

### Code

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"START");
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var m = new MyCls();
    });
    Console.WriteLine($"t.Start");
    t.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to create a new object");

    try
    {
        var m2 = new MyCls();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}


public class MyCls
{
    static MyCls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"sctor calling Abort on itself");
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            };
            Console.WriteLine($"sctor.{i}");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
START
t.Start
sctor.0
sctor.1
sctor.2
sctor.3
sctor calling Abort on itself
Trying to create a new object
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyCls' threw an exception. ---> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort()
   at Program.MyCls..cctor() in c:\users\letss\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 42
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Program.MyCls..ctor()
   at Program.Main() in c:\users\letss\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 21
All done
```

Comment: My example doesn't just show that a static constructor may not be interrupted, it also shows that the calling thread is blocked, and the case where `Thread.Abort()` blocks the calling thread is likely to happen (only?) with _protected regions of code_.

Comment: Got ya. You're more about the blocking rather than aborting.